# Value error while converting tensor to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torch, resnet

I'm using the following code to extract the features from image.

```
def ext():
    imgPathList = glob.glob("images/"+"*.JPG")
    features = []
    for i, path in enumerate(tqdm(imgPathList)):
        feature = get_vector(path)
        feature = feature[0] / np.linalg.norm(feature[0])
        features.append(feature)
        paths.append(path)
    features = np.array(features, dtype=np.float32)
    return features, paths
```

However, the above code throws the following error,

```
 features = np.array(features, dtype=np.float32)
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

How can I be able to fix it?

Comment: This is very suspect for something that's supposed to be a scalar: `feature[0] / np.linalg.norm(feature[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that your `features` variable is a list which contains multi dimensional values which cant be converted to tensor, because `.append` is converting the tensors to list, So some workaround is to use concatenation function of torch as `torch.cat()` (read [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.cat.html)) instead of append method. I tried to replicate the solution with toy example.

I am assuming that features contain 2D tensor

```
import torch
for i in range(1,11):
    alpha = torch.rand(2,2)
    if i<2:
        beta = alpha #will concatenate second sample
    else:
        beta = torch.cat((beta,alpha),0)
    
import numpy as np

features = np.array(beta, dtype=np.float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a list of `tensors` you can not convert directly like that.

You need to convert internal tensors into NumPy array first (Use [`torch.Tensor.numpy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.numpy) to convert tensor into the array) and then list of NumPy array to the final array.

```
features = np.array([item.numpy() for item in features], dtype=np.float32)
```